# Storing functions in an R list

Tags: r, list, eval

I'm trying to build a shiny app to help with a decision analysis. In part of the app, the user is required to enter their utility function as text, which R/shiny will convert to an expression. Suppose the user has three parts to their utility functions which will be combined into a larger utility function. The problem I have is defining the list elements in a `for`  loop:

```
utility.fns <- list()

ufs <- list() ## user input

## each ufs is specified by the user

ufs[[1]] <- "x+1"
ufs[[2]] <- "sin(x)"
ufs[[3]] <- "cos(x)^2"


for(i in 1:3){

  ## turn the text into functions

  utility.fns[[i]] <- function(x){
   eval( parse(text = ufs[[i]]) )
  }
}



utility.fns[[1]](1) ## returns cos(1)^2 ?
```

The weird thing is that the list `utility.fns` always returns `utility.fns[[3]]`, regardless of the index. However, manually overriding

```
> utility.fns[[1]] <- function(x){
+   eval( parse(text = ufs[[1]]) )
+ }
> utility.fns[[1]](1)
[1] 2
```

fixes the issue. Obviously I can't manually override every time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it always returns `utility.fns[[3]]` is because if you check `utility.fns`

```
utility.fns[[1]]

#function(x){
#    eval( parse(text = ufs[[i]]) )
#}
#<bytecode: 0x1223d31c8>
```

The `i` in for loop ended at 3 so it invokes `ufs[[3]]` always.

You could keep functions in `ufs` itself assign the value to `x` and then use `eval`, `parse`

```
x <- 1
eval(parse(text = ufs[[1]]))
#[1] 2
eval(parse(text = ufs[[2]]))
#[1] 0.841
eval(parse(text = ufs[[3]]))
#[1] 0.292
```

Comment: Thanks! I think avoiding loops has fixed my problem ```utility.fns <- function(x,i){
   eval(parse(text = ufs[[i]])) 
  }```

Answer (score 1):

Use `lapply` instead of a `for`

```
utility.fns <- lapply(1:3, function(i){function(x){eval(parse(text = ufs[[i]]) )}})
```